# implementation view-pager in different size

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, adapter

I would like to show the viewpager in different view size

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return(1/5f);
}
```

this method just show the view in the same size 
can't show the different view in different size

Which method should I override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

```
getPageWidth{}
```

override this method can solved the problem

such as return (position+1)/5f;